# How to use autoprefixer with postcss and Grunt on more than one file?

Tags: gruntjs, postcss

The title says it all. My postcss task is as follows:

```
    postcss: {

      options: {

          processors: [
              require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['last 2 versions']}),
              require('cssnext')(),
              require('precss')()
            ]
      },
      dist: {
          src: '*.css',
          dest: 'style.css',
      }

    },
```

Currently I have another css file called style-human, which I want to prefix also. However, the task only prefixes the style.css file (the minified version).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The Problem

The problem lies in your `src:` and `dest:` config. With `src: '*.css'` you are asking the postcss task to process all the .css files it finds, then with `dest: style.css` you ask for all the processed .css files to be output to one file called `style.css`. `grunt-postcss` only writes the last file it processed to `style.css`.

## Solutions

There are several solutions to your problem.

### #1

**First** if you don't specify a `dest` option `grunt-postcss` will process and update all the `src` files in place, overwriting the originals:

```
postcss: {
  options: {
    processors: [
      require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['last 2 versions']}),
      require('cssnext')(),
      require('precss')()
    ]
  },
  dist: {
    src: '*.css'
  }
}
```

not so good if you want to keep your `src` files.

### #2

**You could** use the [files](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files) option with `expand`.

```
postcss: {
  options: {
    processors: [
      require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['last 2 versions']}),
      require('cssnext')(),
      require('precss')()
    ]
  },
  dist: {
    files: [
      {
        src: '*.css',
        dest: 'build/',
        expand: true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This will process all your .css files, and output them to the `build/` folder.

### #3

**Use** [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) to copy your css files to your output folder, like `/build`, then process them in place with `grunt-postcss`.
A full example:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');
  grunt.registerTask('css', ['copy:postcss', 'postcss']);

  grunt.initConfig({
    copy: {
      postcss: {
        files: [
          {
            src: 'css/*.css',
            dest: './build/',
            expand: true,
            flatten: true
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    postcss: {
      options: {
        map: true, // inline sourcemaps

        processors: [
          require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['last 2 versions']}),
          require('postcss-cssnext')(),
          require('precss')()
        ]
      },
      dist: {
        files: [
          {
            src: 'build/*.css'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });
};
```

For an explanation of the `expand` and `flatten` options see the grunt docs on [files](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files).

Here we use the `copy` task to copy the src css files to the build folder, then we use the `postcss` task to process them in place. I've created an [alias](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#alias-tasks) task with `grunt.registerTask('css', ['copy:postcss', 'postcss']);` that you can call to run both steps with `grunt css`.

### #4

**If you want to concatenate** your files into one css file (my preferred way of using postcss), then create a `main.css` file and either use precss's [@import](https://github.com/jonathantneal/precss#imports) or [postcss-import](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import) to pull all your other css files into `main.css`. Like so:

```
postcss: {
  options: {
    processors: [
      require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['last 2 versions']}),
      require('cssnext')(),
      require('precss')()
    ]
  },
  dist: {
    src: 'main.css',
    dest: 'build/main.css'
  }
}
```

main.css:

```
@import "style.css";
@import "style-human.css";
```

Here `postcss` takes care of locating, processing and concatenating your css files, and the `grunt` task only has to worry about `main.css`.

## FYI

You should use the `postcss-cssnext` package instead of `cssnext` as the `cssnext` package hasn't been updated in months.

Also using `postcss-cssnext` and `autoprefixer` together is redundant because `postcss-cssnext` includes `autoprefixer` already.

Comment: Thank you, Andrien. The first solution works perfectly for me as I don't need to create other files. 
I was first looking for a way to add more files to dest: 'style.css'. :)